# How to branch multiple times in SuperH assembly?

Tags: assembly

I wrote a SuperH assembly subroutine that draws a pixel to the screen:

```
# r3: x coord
# r4: y coord
# r5: pixel color
draw_pixel:
  mov.l frame_buffer_address, r0
  mov.l screen_width, r6
  mul.l r6, r4
  sts macl, r4
  add r4, r3
  add r3, r0

  mov r5, r1
  mov.b r1, @r0 

  rts 
  nop
```

I can then branch from my program with:

```
  mov #20, r3
  mov #50, r4
  mov #10, r5
  bsr draw_pixel
  nop
```

This works perfectly, and I can do it multiple times with different parameters, it all works.

I start to run into trouble when I try to branch to draw_pixel from another subroutine. (I want to draw a rectangle but for now I am just drawing a single pixel until it works correctly)

```
draw_rect:
  mov #50, r3
  mov #20, r4
  mov #4, r5
  bsr draw_pixel
  nop

  rts
  nop
```

Which I try to call from my program with:

```
  bsr draw_rect
  nop
```

This does not work. I suspect it has something to do with branching to draw_rect to draw_pixel, since the code is identical as the code that worked, the only thing that has changed is just an additional subroutine / branch in the mix.

I feel like there is something extra I need to consider when doing nested branching, but not exactly sure what that would be. Or perhaps there is a different sort of mistake I'm making here.

Also please note I'm using immediate values just for testing, I'll use variables once I get it working.

Edit:

The solution is to save pr before branching to draw_pixel:

```
sts pr, r9
```

and then restore pr before returning from draw_rect:

```
lds r9, pr
```

Comment: Have you saved `pr` in the outer routine so that outer routine can use the right return address upon its return?  It's a register, so another `bsr` will repurpose it, loosing the original value.

Comment: If you fail to save and restore `pr` properly, the effect will be that the `rts` from the outer function will return to a call site within that same function, instead of returning to the actual caller — this will generally appear as an infinite loop in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/cd00147165-sh-4-32-bit-cpu-core-architecture-stmicroelectronics.pdf) the `bsr` instruction performs the following operations:

> Delayed branch, PC + 4 → PR,
> disp × 2 + PC + 4 → PC

In other words, it first saves the return address in the procedure register (PR), then sets the program counter (PC) to the address of the procedure.

Equivalently, the `rts` instruction does:

> Delayed branch, PR → PC

That is, it restores the program counter value that was previously saved by `bsr`.

Here's the problem: the first time you use the `bsr` instruction (`bsr draw_rect`), the processor saves the address of the next instruction in `PR`, so it knows how to return from the procedure. Then you use `bsr` again (`bsr draw_pixel`) and it does that again. So you're effectively losing the original value of `PR`.

When `draw_pixel` returns, it will return to the `nop` after `bsr draw_pixel`, as expected. However, when `draw_rect` returns, it will also return to the same place, since that's where `PR` points to.

To solve that, you need to save `PR` somewhere else (another register or the stack), then restore it before returning.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something...